# Showing share services options every time

Tags: android, share

I am trying to add a share button for my android app that can show share options every time a user wants to share. The app currently goes directly to gmail because i had selected gmail in the first attempt but doesn't show Whatsapp or facebook apps on the second attempt. It seems my phone sets the first app as default. How do i go about this. Kindly help.

```
public static void shareApp(Activity activity) {
    try {
        final String appPackageName = activity.getPackageName();
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, activity.getResources().getString(R.string.share_text) + " https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        activity.startActivity(sendIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [clearPackagePreferredActivities](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#clearPackagePreferredActivities(java.lang.String)) before broadcast your intent.

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
pm.clearPackagePreferredActivities("you_package_name");
```